# javascript regex - Return value unless followed by or preceded with

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a few different string combinations and I am trying to return results in this format:

`[0-9]{1,3}GB` unless it is preceded by `SD` somewhere in the string, or followed by `RAM` somewhere in the string.

Thus:

`8 GB` should return: `8 GB`

`8 GB RAM` should return:

`SD Card 8 GB` should return:

`microSD, up to 32 GB` should return:

`16 GB` should return: `16 GB`

This `(([0-9]{1,3}GB)(?!\s+RAM)(?!SD))` doesn't work with javascript based regex.

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: I'm not sure regex is capable of doing negative matches for strings of arbitrary length. IMO you should do a first round where you filter out all strings matching `SD.*\d{1,3} ?GB` and `\d{1,3} ?GB.*RAM`, and then run `(\d{1,3} ?GB)` on the resulting list of strings.

Comment: Do you expect an input string to contain one single or multiple matches? See https://regex101.com/r/qO8xN1/2

Comment: None of those strings match `[0-9]{1,3}GB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do with a single regex using alternation to check for presence of a capturing group:

```js
var arr = ['8 GB', '8 GB RAM', 'SD Card 8 GB', 'microSD, up to 32 GB', '16 GB'];
var re = /SD.*\d{1,3}\s*GB|(\d{1,3}\s*GB)(?!.*\bRAM)/i;

var res = [];
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   var m = arr[i].match(re);
   res.push(m && m[1] || '');
}

console.log(res);
//=> ["8 GB", "", "", "", "16 GB"]
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `SD.*\d{1,3}\s*GB` - Match `SD` followed by 1-3 digits and `GB`
- `|` - OR
- `(\d{1,3}\s*GB)` - Match 1-3 digits and `GB` and **group it in captured group #1**
- `(?!.*\bRAM)` - Negative lookahead to fail the match if we have `RAM` after current position

So we are matching and ignoring first part in alternation and keeping only 2nd one which is in a group. We are only storing captured group in our result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with a single regex, but here's a function:

```js
function extract_match(str) {
  // there can be no matches past "SD"
  str = str.replace(/SD[\s\S]*$/, '');

  var m = /\d{1,3} *GB(?![\s\S]*RAM)/.exec(str);
  return m && m[0];
}

function test(str) {
  console.log('input: "' + str + '"; result: ' + extract_match(str));
}

test('8 GB');
test('8 GB RAM');
test('SD Card 8 GB');
test('microSD, up to 32 GB');
test('16 GB');
```

If you want to be cute, you can compress the function to `str => (/\d{1,3} *GB(?![\s\S]*RAM)/.exec(str.replace(/SD[\s\S]*$/, '')) || [null])[0]`.